# Rails Test error ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning Rails Tutorial. When I did rails test at chapter 10. I got this error.
I could make many fake users by ruby gem 'faker'.
however, it seems db does not have lana from users.yml.
I think that is the reason why the error occurred when I did rails test.

```
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "lana".
```

I commanded

```
rails db:reset
rails db:seed
```

## test/fixtures/users.yml

```
michael: 
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

  lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

malory:
  name: Malory Archer
  email: boss@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
<% end %>
```

## error log

```
  1) Error:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "lana".


Error:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass


  2) Error:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "lana".


Error:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Could you give me advice to solve this, please?

Comment: The yml file is often 'indentation sensitive', i would suggest you remove the space before `lana` just like the others

Comment: Thanks. The answer was as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong change the lana section for this:

```
archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know indentation is such sensitive for yml file.